# Pure JSONP request with Ajax using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Ok. I have searched everywhere and didnt find any understandable answer. 
Please note its the first time i'm implementing this kind of request. ("Happens to everyone i think"):P
The problem: I have a json file say for example https://www.example.com/something.json and i want to request it through JSONP using Ajax.
I've read that in order to make a JSONP request you have to wrap data to a callback function. So i edited my php file that generates the json file and added the $_GET('callback') function to wrap data. So if i type to a browser https://www.example.com/something.json/?callback=jsonpCallBack i can see my data wrapping jsonpCallBack([{.......}]);

In jQuery now i am trying to access this information and append the data to html every 20 seconds. 
So i have

```
      var url='https://www.example.com/something.json/?callback=jsonpCallBack';

      var main= $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url : url, 
                dataType:'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback:'jsonpCallBack',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    .......
                     var outputhtml='<ul>';
                     var item = [];
                      for(var i =0; i < data.length-1 ;i++)
                      {

                        var item = data[i];
                        ..........
                     $('.div').html(outputhtml) ;
                }

            });

setInterval(function() {
    main;
},20000);

    main;
```

But instead i can't see my data updating. Did i miss something? Do i still have to use $.getJSON() function to get the data? and if yes where is going to be added in the code?

Lots of confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var main = function() {
    var url = 'https://www.example.com/something.json/';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (result) {
            ...
        }
    });
};

window.setInterval(main, 20000);
main();
```

Which will work if `https://www.example.com/something.json/?callback=foobar` returns the following result (which you mentioned being the case in your question, right?):

```
foobar({...})
```

Comment: This will work for Cross domain requests? I am already allowing to all the CORS.

Comment: This will work for cross domain AJAX requests if you have already made your server side script return `JSONP` instead of `JSON`.

Comment: I have tried the code above but the data are not updated with every ajax request. I am also getting this warning in Chrome:

 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.example.com/json/something.json/?callback=jsonp1365783919785". jquery.min.js:127
c.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:127
(anonymous function) widget.js:58
c.extend.ready

But when i hit refresh of the page the data are changing!! Thats something weird!:S

Comment: How to make my server side return `JSONP` instead of `JSON`. Any special trick here I missed?

Comment: @Blaise, that will very much depend on the specific framework and implementation you are using on the server.